# Compile Problem with RFDuino RFD22301

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors

I have the following setup:
- Arduino IDE for Mac 1.8.5
- RFDuino RFD220301
- CP2102 USB to UART connector
- Board set to "RFduino"
- port set correctly (but shouldn't matter as it is a compile error)
- Programmer: AVRISP mkII

When trying to compile an example script using BLE (Such as AdvertisementContinuous) I get the following error

arm-none-eabi-g++: error: /var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_188605/core/syscalls.c.o: No such file or directory

Any ideas?

Here's the -v log:

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Mac OS X), Board: "RFduino"

/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/julian/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=RFduino:RFduino:RFduino -ide-version=10805 -build-path /var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_cache_722169 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arm-none-eabi-gcc.path=/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1 -verbose /Users/julian/Code/openSleep/embedded/sleepduino/sleepduino.ino
/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware -hardware /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder -tools /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr -tools /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages -built-in-libraries /Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/libraries -libraries /Users/julian/Documents/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=RFduino:RFduino:RFduino -ide-version=10805 -build-path /var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200 -warnings=none -build-cache /var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_cache_722169 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arm-none-eabi-gcc.path=/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1 -verbose /Users/julian/Code/openSleep/embedded/sleepduino/sleepduino.ino
Using board 'RFduino' from platform in folder: /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3
Detecting libraries used...
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sketch/sleepduino.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sketch/sleepduino.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE/RFduinoBLE.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
Generating function prototypes...
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin  -w -x c++ -E -CC -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sketch/sleepduino.ino.cpp" -o "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"/Applications/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin -MMD -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sketch/sleepduino.ino.cpp" -o "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sketch/sleepduino.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling library "RFduinoBLE"
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin -MMD -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE/RFduinoBLE.cpp" -o "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/libraries/RFduinoBLE/RFduinoBLE.cpp.o"
Compiling core...
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-builtin -MMD -mcpu=cortex-m0 -DF_CPU=16000000 -DARDUINO=10805 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/cores/arduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/RFduino/include" "-I/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/system/CMSIS/CMSIS/Include" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino/variant.cpp" -o "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/core/variant.cpp.o"
Using precompiled core
Linking everything together...
"/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/tools/arm-none-eabi-gcc/4.8.3-2014q1/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++" -Wl,--gc-sections --specs=nano.specs -mcpu=cortex-m0 -mthumb -D__RFduino__ "-T/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino/linker_scripts/gcc/RFduino.ld" "-Wl,-Map,/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sleepduino.ino.map" -Wl,--cref -o "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sleepduino.ino.elf" "-L/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200" -Wl,--warn-common -Wl,--warn-section-align -Wl,--start-group "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/core/syscalls.c.o" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/sketch/sleepduino.ino.cpp.o" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/libraries/RFduinoBLE/RFduinoBLE.cpp.o" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/core/variant.cpp.o" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino/libRFduinoSystem.a" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino/libRFduino.a" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino/libRFduinoBLE.a" "/Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/variants/RFduino/libRFduinoGZLL.a" "/var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/../arduino_cache_722169/core/core_RFduino_RFduino_RFduino_96c93913732efe419124a59ff97a44c7.a" -Wl,--end-group
arm-none-eabi-g++: error: /var/folders/m6/mfwpb8b13wn4f9fvb4lhx_v40000gp/T/arduino_build_997200/core/syscalls.c.o: No such file or directory
Using library RFduinoBLE in folder: /Users/julian/Library/Arduino15/packages/RFduino/hardware/RFduino/2.3.3/libraries/RFduinoBLE (legacy)
exit status 1
Error compiling for board RFduino.
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this using 1.8.3. I installed https://github.com/RFduino/RFduino in the board manager and used the https://github.com/RFduino/RFduino/blob/master/libraries/RFduinoBLE/examples/AdvertisementContinuous/AdvertisementContinuous.ino sketch. It compiles fine. Can you go into the Arduino IDE settings and activate verbose output on compiling and edit your question with that log?

Answer (score 1):

So it appears solved: Using Arduino 1.6.13 I don't get the compile error. Must be an incompatibility with the RFduino Board libraries and the 1.8x IDE.